# How to copy to ProgramFiles (X86) Via Script (From SCCM/ConfigMgr)

Tags: powershell, sccm, copy-item

I'm trying to copy an AdobeOverride file from a location on the `C:\` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\UpdateResource\`

This works perfectly fine for the copy to the `ProgramData` location but not `Program Files (x86)` I'm assuming my issue is around spacing between Program Files and Common Files. I did try using the Environment variable `${env:CommonProgramFiles(x86)}\Adobe\UpdateResouce` but same result. I did try Single quotes and a backtick at the space but again same result.

My script is running from Sccm\Configuration Manager which I believe should run script at System Level context.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
$URL = “Internal FTP Server”
$TestPath86 = Test-path -path "C:\Program Files'(x86')\Common Files\Adobe\UpdateResources"
$TestPath64 = Test-path -path "C:\ProgramData\Adobe\AAMUpdater\1.0"
$Dest = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\UpdateResources\"
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -OutFile "C:\IT-Extra\Override.zip"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Expand-Archive C:\IT-Extra\Override.zip -DestinationPath C:\IT-Extra\
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Remove-Item C:\IT-Extra\Override.zip

if ( $TestPath86 -eq $true) {
    Remove-item "C:\Program Files'(x86')\Common Files\Adobe\UpdateResources\AdobeUpdater.Override
    Copy-Item -Path 'C:\IT-Extra\AdobeUpdater.Overrides' -Destination $Dest -Force

}

if ( $TestPath64 -eq $true) {
    Remove-item "C:\ProgramData\Adobe\AAMUpdater\1.0\AdobeUpdater.Overrides"
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\IT-Extra\AdobeUpdater.Overrides" -Destination "C:\ProgramData\Adobe\AAMUpdater\1.0" -Force
}
```

Comment: Are you using the "Application" or "Package/Program" model of SCCM? Programs are always run in 32Bit context, so the folder "programfiles x86" doesn't exist there and is just called programfiles because of wow64

Answer (score 1):

It's **best to use the `env:CommonProgramFiles(x86)` *environment variable***<sup>[1]</sup> to refer to the program-files path for 32-bit applications (the same goes analogously for other well-known paths, such as `ProgramData` for `C:\ProgramData`), which in PowerShell requires the form `${env:CommonProgramFiles(x86)}`,<sup>[2]</sup> e.g.:

```bash
Test-Path -Path "${env:CommonProgramFiles(x86)}\Adobe\UpdateResources"
```

Note that the string in which the environment-variable reference is embedded is of necessity *double*-quoted (`"..."`), i.e. an [*expandable* (interpolating) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings).

---

If you do want to **hard-code the path**, do *not* embed `'` instances in it - just make sure that it is used inside a quoted string overall (given that it contains spaces and `(` and `)`):

```bash
Test-Path -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\UpdateResources'
```

Note that since the string now doesn't contain any variable references, it's better to use a *sinqle*-quoted (`'...'`) string, i.e. a [*verbatim* string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings).

---

<sup>[1] While rare in practice, it is possible to configure Windows systems to use paths other than the default locations for well-known paths. The environment variables can be relied on to point to such redirected locations too. An alternative way to determine paths safely is via the [`System.Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.GetFolderPath) .NET API: `[Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::CommonProgramFilesX86)`. Tip of the hat to [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42).</sup>

<sup>[2] The enclosure of the variable name in `{...}` following the `$` is only necessary if the name contains special characters, such as `(` and `)` in this case. Usually, that isn't necessary, such as in the case of `$env:OS`</sup>